# Spring bean set values taken from properties file

Tags: spring, properties

I have a spring bean defined like

```
<util:set id="siteLanguages" value-type="java.util.Locale" set-class="java.util.LinkedHashSet">
    <value>#{T(java.util.Locale).GERMAN}</value>
    <value>#{T(java.util.Locale).ITALIAN}</value>
    <value>#{T(java.util.Locale).ENGLISH}</value>
</util:set>
```

I'm wondering how can I pass the value list definitions to the bean as a properties list value.

```
<util:set id="siteLanguages" value-type="java.util.Locale" set-class="java.util.LinkedHashSet">
        ???
</util:set>
```

I would like to have in my properties file something like

```
site.languages=#{T(java.util.Locale).GERMAN},#{T(java.util.Locale).ITALIAN},#{T(java.util.Locale).ENGLISH}
```

or even better

```
site.languages=GERMAN,ITALIAN,ENGLISH
```

and pass this in to the bean

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you cannot express multivalue data structures (arrays, lists etc) in plain java property files by using the java standard api.

You can do it easily though with Apache commons configuration library.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/